# How are code segments and data segments of a source code program really handled and separated from each other during process execution?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, ram

Consider the following picture showing a RAM within which is stored a very simple program divided into instruction block and data block. The example is very similar to the ones found in the book "Code" by Charles Petzold:

[image]

As you see there's an instruction block and a data block. In the book this RAM is put inside a rudimentary computer within which you have to put manually both data and instructions by using some switches (just like the old altair 8800). In order for the machine to start executing instructions you had to set the initial address of instruction block and then the machine started executing one instruction after the other sequentially. Basically all this program does is loading the value 1 into accumulator, then add 5 to it, store the result in the address 000Ch (h stands for hex) and finally it stops executing with Halt instruction.

Now when I try to connect the knowledge I got from this book to the way a C source code is compiled I get a bit confused. Specifically the phase in which there's some separation between code segment and data segment. Consider this simple source code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int test=10;

int main(){

test ++;
return 0;

}
```

Now my idea is that the compiler should tell the computer to execute machine instructions like this :

```
int test=10; -> STORE [addressX],10 

int main()
{

test++; -> LOAD A,[addressX]
        -> INR  A
        -> STORE [addressX],A

    return 0;
}
```

According to the definition of Wikipedia the data segment "contains initialized static variables, i.e. global variables and local static variables which have a defined value and can be modified".
In my simple example the variable test is a global variable.
However my idea is that before the variable is put inside the data segment of the RAM some sort of machine instructions like STORE must have been invoked. Otherwise how can the global variable be stored inside RAM?

Can someone explain in detail what is really happening and how the simple source code I showed here is really divided into text segment and data segment. What is exactly the text segment for this example? And what about the data segment?

I hope you understood what my doubt is and be able to answer as clear as possible. I appreciate if you could also address me to some good and in deep (with example and not abstract) resources to understand what's really going on when dealing with code, data, stack and heap segments.

Comment: On Windows and [`Portable Executable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format), there is no such a need to execute a *STORE* instruction to store a global variable or initialized/uninitialized data in Ram.

Comment: The "separation" is totally artificial. The code and data can very well reside in the same memory region. The compiler jut needs to make sure the execution starts at the address of the first instruction. Then the data and the code can even be mixed, but the compiler should make sure there are instructions that "jump" over the data parts. Of course it is a pathological example, in practice the compilers usually *do* separate the sections, but it is absolutely not necessary.

Comment: The compiler doesn't load the code into memory.  That is the job of the OS or the human with the toggle switches.

Comment: Of course there must be a STORE instruction to fill the memory with the initial value. The compiler will usually place the variables into an object file as initialized memory, and the linker will create the memory section with all initialized variables in some file. Depending on your system, the OS may load code + data sections from an executable file, or both the code and a copy of the data section may be stored in FLASH memory, and there will be some startup code that will copy a memory block from FLASH to RAM, so the STORE instr. for the initial value is part of OS or startup/runtime lib.

Answer (score 1):

I can explain how things work roughly on Windows.

First of all, the given information in the book does not apply that much to modern nowadays OSes. Most OS (such as Windows, Linux, etc.) has an executable file format that describes how the code and data are stored within the file, how they can be mapped into RAM, where to start to execute the code so on. On Windows, the format is called [`Portable Executable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format). PE format consists of zero or more [`sections`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-image_section_header) to store the code and other data. Sections contain some important information such as how the OS will find the data of the section in the file, how to map this data to the memory, what kind of protection method will be used for this data in the memory. Sections can also have a name such as `.text`, `.data`, `.bss`, `.idata`, `.rdata` giving a clue about what kind of data the section contains.

When you compile and link your code with MSVC on Windows, you have a portable executable file for your program. This PE file will have one or more sections. For your example, it may have a `.text` for code, a `.data` for initialized data, and a `.idata` section for your imports from other modules. `.text` section has the compiled machine code, `.data` section has the data of value 10 for the variable `test`. When you execute the file, the OS loader will try to load, parse and map it into the memory created for its process.

So, you don't need a STORE instruction to store and initialize the data in RAM. All data in your program is located at the corresponding section and will be mapped into memory by the loader.

Comment: ... and the mapping of the data into memory will contain some kind of STORE operation somewhere in the OS. Of course you are right that the compiler does not need to put a STORE instruction into the generated code for the program.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. There must be a "STORE" instruction somewhere. I just considered it from the perspective of program code.